# Matlab Questions about Audioplayer GUI

Tags: matlab, audio

I am quite new to Matlab and I am trying to make a program where there are 3 push buttons.

Question 1:

Button 1 will be linked to an audio file (.wav)
So when I press it, Button 1 will "select" the first audio file.

Button 2 will be linked to another audio file (.wav)
So when I press it, Button 2 will "select" the second audio file.

Then, I need to press Button 3 to play the sound file selected, based on which button I pushed first(Button 1/Button 2)

So my current code is like this:
**Button 1 and 2:**

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.wav'},'Load Wav File');
[x,Fs] = wavread([PathName '/' FileName]);
```

**Button 3:**

```
player = audioplayer(x,Fs);
play(player);
```

Ok, so my first problem is that when I run this code, I have to manually select the file. I am not too sure how to make it already link to the file, so I need help on that part...

My second problem is actually about the audioplayer...
For Button 3, it is actually not working... and no sound is played out.
I tried `sound (x,Fs)` before but I search online and they say I have to manually give the command clear sound to stop the .wav file from continuing.

How do is solve this problem? Because I think if I use a fourth button with the code:

```
stop(player)
```

it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer is starting to get a bit messy, so i'll post here a fully working simple example. In this GUI, there are 3 pushButtons (Play, Pause and Stop), and one .wav file  played (piano2.wav).

```
function varargout = AudioTest(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @AudioTest_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @AudioTest_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%      Opening function       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



function AudioTest_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)


handles.output = hObject;
handles.myPlayer=[];

% Update handles structure

guidata(hObject, handles);





function varargout = AudioTest_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 


varargout{1} = handles.output;


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%  Executed on press of Play button   %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function Play_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[x,Fs]=wavread('piano2.wav');
handles.myPlayer=audioplayer(x,Fs);
play(handles.myPlayer);
guidata(hObject,handles);


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%  Executed on press of Pause button   %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function Pause_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


pause(handles.myPlayer);


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%  Executed on press of Stop button   %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


function Stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

stop(handles.myPlayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

-First of all you have to know that the variables you define inside the Callback functions are NOT stored, which is why your Button 3 doesn't work.

-Have you tried running an audio file directly to check if it works before programming the GUI?

-Several tips for what you are trying to do :

1) If you don't want to manually select the file, just set :

filename='full path to your .wav file';

2) To construct the string containing the full path if you have FileName and PathName, you can do :

```
FullPath=strcat(PathName,FileName);
```

3) What kind of buttons are button 1 and button 2? Why do you need pushbuttons if it's just to select a file. I'd suggest :

- radio buttons :  It will be much more intuitive in that case, plus you can get their state programmatically in your Button3_Callback to read the right .wav
- ListBox : Useful if you plan on being able to easily add the possibility to read more .wav files without having to change your GUI.

4) About your last question, it's again due to the fact that variables are not transmitted between Callbacks, so in your Button4_Callback, Matlab doesn't know the variable 'player'.

I'll post more details when you answer my questions ^^

**EDIT** - About your comment :

a) You shouldn't use the  **`function uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)'** To call your code, as you can do everything on the click of Button3. (**function Button3_Callback(hObject,eventdata,handles**))

b) I suggest you to give custom names for your GUI elements (change Tag property in property editor), for example Button3 would be 'play' or something like that. (Imagine a GUI wit 35 buttons, 25 edit fields and so on, you would get lost pretty quickly)

c) The Button3_Callback would look like :

```
%Know which radiobutton is selected

Value_radiobutton1=get(handles.radiobutton1,'value'); %Returns 1 if radiobutton1 is checked, 0 if not

Value_radiobutton2=get(handles.radiobutton2,'value'); %Same as above but for radiobutton2

%Now that you have the information :

if(Value_radiobutton1)

% play first .wav

FullPath='C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test1';

[x,Fs]=wavread(FullPath);

handles.myPlayer = audioplayer(x,Fs);

play(handles.myPlayer);



else

% play second.wav

end

%store your handles again to keep track of your audioplayer.

guiData(hObject,handles);
```

Note that as soon as the callback stops executing the audiofile will stop playing, so you have to use a little trick there, see for example : 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/328757
Note also that after the Callback is executed, your player variable is deleted, so you won't be able to reach it anymore. I'd suggest you store a handle to it in the **handles** object. This can be done for example in the opening function of your GUI before the `guidata(hObject,handles)`by adding something like :

```
handles.myPlayer=[];
```

And then overriding it in your Button3_Callback function

Instead of writing : `player=audioplayer[x,Fs]`

You go for : `handles.myPlayer=audioplayer[x,Fs]`

Then, you can access it to pause/stop the audio.

Now you still have to :

- Find a way to make the music stop playing (button click? Same button that for play?)
- Prevent the user from checking both radio buttons at the same time
- Prevent the user from pressing button3 without having checked a radiobutton
  (maybe by disabling the button3 until a radiobutton is checked, or checking one of the radio buttons by default, your choice).

Comment: I have tried running the audio file before while using `sound `(x,Fs)`

I will try 1 and 2 when on Monday. 

I will try radio buttons as well

Thanks for the suggestionns

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very delayed try on your advice >.<
I have tried out the things that you told me to but I receive errors while programming the radio buttons. I also got confused about your point 1 and 2 as I tried to add it into the program.

**Program**:

`function uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag');
    case 'radiobutton1' 
    test1 = 'C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test1'
    FullPath1 = strcat('C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB','test1');
    [y,Fs] = load('C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test1');
    [y,Fs] = wavread;
    end'

Comment: Hey, why are you doing this in function uipanel1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)? It would be way better to do it in Button3_Callback(hObject,eventdata,handles) (function that gets called when the user presses Button3). Then, you are missing a \ in your strcat call. Anyways either you fetch Filename and PathName programmatically as you did before, or you directly enter it as you're doing with your test1.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: 1. Find a way to make the music stop playing (button click? Same button that for play?) -> I need help for this as well >.< I am planning to use another button for this btw. Will be searching for help.
2. Prevent the user from checking both radio buttons at the same time
-> I manage to solve this problem by using button group)
3. Prevent the user from pressing button3 without having checked a radiobutton (maybe by disabling the button3 until a radiobutton is checked, or checking one of the radio buttons by default, your choice).
-> It will have 1 button alr selected(cant unselect)

Comment: For the stop button : Imagine you had access to the variable 'player', how would you do it?

Comment: if(Value_radiobutton1)
FullPath='C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test1';
[x,Fs]=wavread(FullPath);
player = audioplayer(x,Fs);
stop(player)


I will try something like that, but will get an error saying it is misplaced or not properly nested

Comment: Did you read until the end and add a handle to the player handle (handles.myPlayer) in the opening function of your GUI BEFORE the guidata command? Then you can just simply do a 'stop(handles.myPlayer)' in order to stop it. But first things first, does the sound play yet?

Comment: Yup,the sound manage to play perfectly fine ;D Thank you! WIll try to implement the stop now

Edit:
I tried the stop(handles.myPlayer), but it doesnt seem to stop
I put it like this for the `handles.myPlayer=audioplayer[x,Fs]`...

`handles.output = hObject;
handles.myPlayer=[];
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);`

Comment: When you define the player in the button3 Callback, do you define it with handles.myPlayer=audioplayer[y,Fs]?

Comment: Alsobi didn't tell you yet, but you need to save your handles at the end of your Button3_Callback in order to be able to reach your player handle. You can do this by adding 'guidata(hObject, handles)' ar the end of your callback

Comment: `Value_radiobutton1 = get(handles.radiobutton1,'value'); %Returns 1 if radiobutton1 is checked, 0 if not
Value_radiobutton2 = get(handles.radiobutton2,'value'); %Same as above but for radiobutton2
%Now that you have the information :
handles.myPlayer=audioplayer(x,Fs)
if(Value_radiobutton1)
% play first .wav
FullPath='C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test1';
[x,Fs]=wavread(FullPath);
player = audioplayer(x,Fs);
playblocking(player);
else(Value_radiobutton2)`

Comment: `% play second.wav
FullPath='C:\Users\Y400\Desktop\ITP Stuff\Decibel Data\test2';
[x,Fs]=wavread(FullPath);
player = audioplayer(x,Fs);
playblocking(player);
end
guidata(hObject, handles);`

Like this? I am not too sure, regarding your 1st comment(42 mins ago), you said (y,fs), should it be (x,fs)

I got some error in uicontrol callback

Comment: Yes it should be [x,fs]. if you just define player=audioplayer(x,Fs), do you think it will magically be stored in your handles structure?

Comment: Sorry >.< I am really a beginner at Matlab so I don't really know much of the coding process. I still can stop the audio. The coding for the stop button is this `function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
stop(handles.myPlayer);`

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Hey, Yes!! You got it!

Comment: You don't need the playblocking(player) line, because you are storing the player in the handles! (my button3_callback works without modifying it since my last edit)

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much! It managed to work! May I ask you a question abt handle.functions?

Comment: This question would need to be asked separately in another topic as it is a totally different question, i'll answer it though as soon as you post it

Comment: how do i define handles in matlab? Because I am trying to make a volume slider. From what I have saw from this website: link[link] It seems like I have to have a "multiplier"(Variable) to multiply the 'x'. At the Opening function of the Gui handles.a=[]; At the slider movement of the Gui: function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) handles.a=get(hObject,'Value'); guidata(hObject,handles); I got the error that a is not defined from the current code I have

Comment: Please ask the question in a separate post/question

Comment: I have posted it in a serperate qns in the following link below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982549/volume-slider-in-matlab