# Volume Slider in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, slider, volume

Link of Previous Post:
[Matlab Questions about Audioplayer GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901413/matlab-questions-about-audioplayer-gui)

I am trying to make a volume slider in Matlab...
So currently what I have in mind from what I have searched is using handles variable to get the slider's value. After that, I am planning to have the variable multiply the (x,fs) in the audioplayer.
My current code for the beginning of the handle is like this...

```
handles.a = []  ; %I don't know what to put for this >.<
handles.output = hObject;
handles.myPlayer=[];
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

My code for the volume slider is like this:

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
handles.a = get(handles.slider1,'Value');
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

And my code for the audioplayer will be something like this(not sure if it will work if I do it this way):

```
FullPath='C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test1'; 
[x,Fs]=wavread(FullPath);
handles.myPlayer = audioplayer(handles.a*x,Fs);
play(handles.myPlayer);`
guidata(hObject, handles)`
```

So when I tried "Playing" the audio after this, I get the following error:
Undefined function or variable 'a'.

Will appreciate it if anyone can guide me on this? >.<

**EDIT**

I manage to solve(?) the error: Undefined Function or Variable 'a'.

My current error now is I am getting this error:
Error using  * Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Above code is edited to have the following error as well...

The " * " comes from when I try to multiply handles.a with x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's now see how we can do to increase/decrease the volume without restarting the sample play :

In the slider1_Callback :

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject,handles,eventdata)

%Pause audioplayer

pause(handles.myPlayer);

%Know how far the user has got in the sample

NewStart=get(handles.myPlayer,'CurrentSample')+1;

%stop current player

stop(handles.myPlayer);

%Reload your sample

[x,Fs]=wavread(FullPath);

%Create a new sample by cutting x and keeping only the lines from NewStart 
%to the end

x=x(NewStart:end,:); 

%Get the value of the slider

Volume=get(handles.slider1,'value');

%Set new audioplayer

handles.myPlayer=audioplayer(x*Volume,Fs);

%Play

play(handles.myPlayer);

% save handles structure

guidata(hObject,handles);
```

How long is your audio sample? If it's too long, it might take some time to load and interrupt play. To reduce loading times, you might consider saving the data (for example in one of your button's 'userdata' property).

Comment: After plugging in, I got the following error: Undefined function or variable 'FullPath'.  

So do I have to go about redefining FullPath again? If so, how do I go about doing it, do I use the if else function?

Comment: I'm sure you can figure this out by yourself, plus it will be more rewarding for you! (you're on the good lead!)

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try to solve it first, if got any error, then may I ask you here?

Comment: Yes, just try what you proposed in your last comment!

Comment: Ok, I have tried it out, there is no errors but it seems to be jumping back to the start with a slight pause though >.<

Comment: What did you add to get the FullPath?

Comment: (You should also link to your previous post in your question for people to understand what you're doing)

Comment: I just edited the qns adding the link alr...
I added Value_radiobutton1 = get(handles.radiobutton1,'value') for the 2 radiobuttons

Comment: And then? What is inside your if else condition?

Comment: At the reload your sample, I did the following:  
if(Value_radiobutton1)  
    FullPath = 'C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test1';  
else  
if(Value_radiobutton2)  
    FullPath = 'C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test2';  
end  
end  

[x,Fs] = wavread(FullPath);

Comment: Did you put the 'x=x(NewStart:end,:);' line after that?

Comment: Yes, aft  [x,Fs] = wavread(FullPath); the rest is follow the above coding already

Comment: Can you run these lines in Matlab workspace please :
[x,Fs] = wavread('C:\Users\Y400\Documents\MATLAB\test2');
whos x

Comment: Did you remove the call to pushbutton1_Callback from my previous answer?

Comment: Oh ok, it finally work, although there is a slight pause...Thank you so much! :D

Comment: May I ask you something?
If I am to make this into a Volume Slider with Decibel as it's unit, what do I have to add?  Does increasing the slider by "1 unit" = 1 magnitude for the "mag2db" thing?
I am guessing it is somewhat similar to this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013627/matlab-sound-generation-with-increased-db-value" but I don't quite get what they are saying as they are using graph I think while mine is the audio itself.

Comment: Or do I have to do something like this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/114183 Not very sure what his linear means though...

Comment: To explain a bit more what is in the links you found - You have a conversion between DB and  volume factor with : DB=20*log10(V) (with V0=1). Meaning that if you ask the user to input Decibels, you'll have to put Volume = 10^(DB/20). Going from -20DB to 20DB wold for example get your factor go from 0.1 to 10, 0 DB being equivalent to a factor V0 (here 1)

Comment: So am I right to say that if my slider is in decibels, I will have to add in Volume = 10^(DB/20) instead where DB is get(handles.slider1,'value')?

Answer (score 1):

In your last post, in order to make the audioplayer object we created visible by the whole program, we had to store it manually in the habdles structure.

Uicontrols like pushbuttons, sliders, edit texts, etc.. though, are stored automatically in the GUI handles structure.

For example, your slider whose tag is 'slider1' can be accessed via 'handles.slider1'.

To get its value, you can just use :

```
get(handles.slider1, 'value');
```

Note that, in the property inspector, you can change its Min and Max attribute to fit your needs (here Min=0 and Max=5 seems quite right).

Now, we'll have to actually change the volume of your audio sample.

An easy way to do it (but which will replay the sample since the beginning), would be to implement the volume modification in the button you use to play the sound (Button3 if i remember well) :

After the line :

```
[x,Fs]=wavread('FullPath');
```

Add :

```
Volume=get(handles.slider1,'value');
```

And then :

```
handles.myPlayer=audioplayer(Volume*x,Fs);
```

Last step is to call the callback of your Button3 in your slider1_Callback :

```
Function     Slider1_Callback(hObject,handles,eventdata)

Button3_Callback(hObject,handles,eventdata);
```

Tell me if this is what you need, or if you want the volume to be increased without restarting the sample from the beginning, which would be a bit harder to do,  but would still be doable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It seems to give me an error when I inserted the following code:  Button3_Callback(hObject,handles,eventdata);  
And yes, I need to increase/decrease volume without restarts

Comment: What's the tag of your play button?

Comment: It is pushbutton1.  
Instead of  Button3_Callback(hObject,handles,eventdata);  , I use pushbutton1_Callback(hObject,handles,eventdata);

Comment: Yes that's it. I'm posting a second answer in order to increase/decrease volume without restarts